# Doing a quick count?

Tags: sql, oracle

I already have my select query of data and I want a quick count of how many rows my select query will return. Is there a way to do this instead of taking out all my 'select fields' and replacing with Count(*)? My query has 58 lines of selected fields, and I don't want to have to take out all out to find the count (running this multiple times for different date ranges).  I'm using Toad for Oracle, and I know the bottom has a print out but because the query has too many results (over 5000), I'm not sure how to quickly find the total count. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do:

```
select count(*)
from (
INSERT-YOUR-QUERY-HERE
)
```

Comment: I tried that your exact format, but now getting this error: "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended" any thoughts?

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect!!

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you can put this in your select list:

```
COUNT(*) OVER ()
```

Comment: Thanks! This is great to use too.